# Is "themselves found in a bad position?" correct?

Tags: verbs, relative-pronouns

I am wondering if it possible to use a pronoun like: "Him", "Her", or "them" (I think we called them relative pronoun) in an active way in a sentence.

For example:

- "Them found in a bad position" If in another sentence (either separated by comma or dot) them is known as "people"
- I know this sentence is not correct, but this other sentence sounds good to me:
  "Themselves found in a bad position"

So is it possible?
Side question: when can I found a relative pronoun like "him" or "them" before a verb in a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on who is in a bad position- the original subject, which you mention is "people", or some new subject.

In the first case, you would want to say "They found themselves in a bad position."  Notice you are basically duplicating the "them" pronoun twice, once as the subject of the verb "found" and again as its object.

In the second case, you would need to specify the new thing, perhaps "They found the lamp in a bad position."

Answer (score 0):

No, these are not correct. I'm not sure exactly what meaning you are trying to put across but the closest I can think of is:

- They were found in a bad position
- They found themselves in a bad position

(or similarly with "he" or "she")

Comment: Thanks for both answer, I accepted the faster to answer